# How to use match case pattern in Spark2 Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I want to use case match in scala to define a list of String. Here is my code:

```
Parametre_mod.targetTableBase match {
              case "DWG_LD_ANOMALIE" => 
                val champs = List("CD_ANOMALIE",
                    "CD_FAMILLE",
                    "LIB_ANOMALIE",
                    "DT_MAJ",
                    "CLASSIFICATION",
                    "NB_REJEUX",
                    "TOP_INDIC_CD_ERREUR", "TOP_COORDONNEE_INVALIDE", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")

              case "DWG_LD_NOTIFICATION" =>
                val champs = List(
                    "ID_NOTIFICATION", "ID_ENTITE", "ID_ENTITE_GARANTE", "CD_SYS_APPELANT", "CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE", "ID_PERSONNE", "EMAIL_DESTINATAIRE", 
                    "NUM_TEL_DESTINATAIRE", "CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT", "CD_TYPE_NOTIFICATION", "CD_TYPE_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE", "REF_EXT_DEST_SOURCE", 
                    "EMAIL_DEST_SOURCE", "NUM_TEL_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE_2", "NB_REJEUX", "TOP_RECYCLAGE", "ID_DOC_STRATEGIE_EDIT", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")
            }

            insertion(df, champs, cstProp)
```

But Eclipse IDE indicates that field champs in insertion function in not defined. How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `champs` you created in just inside the `match` expression. And it cannot be accessed outside of it.

You can assign to `champs` as below

```
val champs = Parametre_mod.targetTableBase match {
  case "DWG_LD_ANOMALIE" => List("CD_ANOMALIE",
      "CD_FAMILLE",
      "LIB_ANOMALIE",
      "DT_MAJ",
      "CLASSIFICATION",
      "NB_REJEUX",
      "TOP_INDIC_CD_ERREUR", "TOP_COORDONNEE_INVALIDE", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")
  case "DWG_LD_NOTIFICATION" => List(
      "ID_NOTIFICATION", "ID_ENTITE", "ID_ENTITE_GARANTE", "CD_SYS_APPELANT", "CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE", "ID_PERSONNE", "EMAIL_DESTINATAIRE",
      "NUM_TEL_DESTINATAIRE", "CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT", "CD_TYPE_NOTIFICATION", "CD_TYPE_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE", "REF_EXT_DEST_SOURCE",
      "EMAIL_DEST_SOURCE", "NUM_TEL_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE_2", "NB_REJEUX", "TOP_RECYCLAGE", "ID_DOC_STRATEGIE_EDIT", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 'champs' outside of match block so that it's available outside as well -

```
var champs:List[String] = List.empty[String]

    Parametre_mod.targetTableBase match {
      case "DWG_LD_ANOMALIE" =>
        champs = List("CD_ANOMALIE",
          "CD_FAMILLE",
          "LIB_ANOMALIE",
          "DT_MAJ",
          "CLASSIFICATION",
          "NB_REJEUX",
          "TOP_INDIC_CD_ERREUR", "TOP_COORDONNEE_INVALIDE", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")

      case "DWG_LD_NOTIFICATION" =>
        champs = List(
          "ID_NOTIFICATION", "ID_ENTITE", "ID_ENTITE_GARANTE", "CD_SYS_APPELANT", "CD_TYPE_DESTINATAIRE", "ID_PERSONNE", "EMAIL_DESTINATAIRE",
          "NUM_TEL_DESTINATAIRE", "CD_TYPE_EVENEMENT", "CD_TYPE_NOTIFICATION", "CD_TYPE_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE", "REF_EXT_DEST_SOURCE",
          "EMAIL_DEST_SOURCE", "NUM_TEL_DEST_SOURCE", "ID_PERSONNE_DEST_SOURCE_2", "NB_REJEUX", "TOP_RECYCLAGE", "ID_DOC_STRATEGIE_EDIT", "TOP_SUPP", "DT_SUPP")
    }
    insertion(df, champs, cstProp)
```

Comment: This would be an anti-pattern in Scala, since you are using an _unnecessary_ `var` since the `match` being an **expression** can return a value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Luis.